# Where are the built-in filters?

Tags: support, api, filter

On [api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter) it states:

> there are a number of built-in filters which cover common use cases.

Where can I find them? Can you make *built-in filters* a link?

I need only a few properties in question and answer. I tried [creating a filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter) but it's not returning exactly what I need.

Comment: I ended up creating a filter that works. That filter creation page is pretty slick.

Comment: Your comment contradicts the last sentence of the question.

Answer (score 3):

"A number of" might be a bit of a misnomer, as there are a whopping four standard ones:

From the [filters documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters):

> `default`, each type documents which fields are returned under the
>   default filter (for example, answers).
>   `withbody`, which is default plus the *.body fields
>   `none`, which is empty
>   `total`, which includes just .total

The page also lists a few filters that can be used for backwards compatibility with API 1.x behaviours, but makes the reasonable assertion that you shouldn't use them for any new application.